Group BSSIDs in WiFi scan from the same physical router
Suppose I am conducting a WiFi scan and I get back a list of BSSIDs that my device can currently see. Is there anything in the WiFi standard that would allow my device to identify which BSSIDs are on the same physical access point?
For example, if each access point is broadcasting the networks "Home" and "Home_Guest" and they're each broadcasting them on 2.4ghz and 5ghz (so, 4 BSSIDs total), I'd like to be able to figure out which 4 BSSIDs belong on the same AP.
I realize I can make some intelligent guesses, based on SSID/channel, or based on taking multiple scans in multiple locations and doing statistical clustering. That's not what I'm looking for.
I also realize some manufacturers have published the schemes that their equipment uses to generate BSSIDs based on the physical MAC address of the AP. This is inconsistent at best, as not all manufacturers have this, and not for all models.
Is there anything in the WiFi spec itself that enables me to match these BSSIDs together?
Happy to receive OS-agnostic answers. In other words, I don't need to know whether this can be implemented on Windows or Linux or Android or whatever, but I'd happily take an answer that shows how to do it on one of those platforms just to prove it can be done. I just want to know if it's even conceptually possible.
